# How can I insert an object in an array of objects in ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby, object, testing, insert

I need to print uniq results inside an array. To test this I need to insert an object inside my array.

```
array = [#<Card id: 394034, cards_config_id: nil>, #<Card id: 394033, cards_config_id: nil>,#<Card id: 394032, cards_config_id: nil>, #<Card id: 394035, cards_config_id: nil>]
```

I need to insert another `Card` object to test uniqueness. 
Something like this `array.uniq &:id`

I know this is wrong but how can I achieve this ?

`array << Card id:394034, cards_config_id: nil>`

Comment: If you want to test if all elements of an array `arr` are unique it’s just `arr == arr.uniq`. Why do you want to insert an element in the array? Please be more clear about the result you want as opposed to what you assume you need to do to achieve that result.

Comment: @CarySwoveland
I know `uniq` will work but I need to test it in case of objects. 
`array.uniq &:id` would work or not.
Also I need to add test cases.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Also, your `array` is not valid Ruby code. Please, show a [mre] that clearly represents the actual problem you are having.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do as below,

```
array = [#<Card id: 394034, cards_config_id: nil>, #<Card id: 394033, cards_config_id: nil>,#<Card id: 394032, cards_config_id: nil>, #<Card id: 394035, cards_config_id: nil>]


array = array | [#<Card id: 394034, cards_config_id: nil>]
```

You can also use [Set](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.3/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html)

```
require 'set'

set = Set[#<Card id: 394034, cards_config_id: nil>, #<Card id: 394033, cards_config_id: nil>,#<Card id: 394032, cards_config_id: nil>, #<Card id: 394035, cards_config_id: nil>]

set.add(#<Card id: 394034, cards_config_id: nil>)
```

As `set` do not allow to have duplicates

Comment: I'm still getting syntax error in both the approaches.

`array = array | [#<Card id:123, cards_config_id: nil>]`

`SyntaxError Exception: (byebug):1: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting ']'
... id:123, cards_config_id: nil>] `

Comment: You can have it like, `array = array | Card.find(123)`

Answer (score 0):

May be you can verify like this as well.

```
class Card
   attr_accessor :id, :cards_config_id
   def initialize(id, cards_config_id = nil)
       @id = id
       @cards_config_id = cards_config_id
   end
end

>many_card = Array.new(2){Card.new(394034)}
=> [#<Card:0x5dd6264 @cards_config_id=nil, @id=394034>, #<Card:0x1ffe63b9 @cards_config_id=nil, @id=394034>]

>  many_card.uniq{|x| x.id}
=> [#<Card:0x5dd6264 @cards_config_id=nil, @id=394034>]
```

I hope that helpful.

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me.

```
array = [#<Card id: 394034, cards_config_id: nil>, #<Card id: 394033, cards_config_id: nil>,#<Card id: 394032, cards_config_id: nil>, #<Card id: 394035, cards_config_id: nil>]

array << Card.find(123)
```